# replace selected escaped characters from the xml data

Tags: xml, xslt

I am very new to XML data processing, please help me building the XSLT code for replacing the selected escaped characters,

Replace

1. `&gt;` with `>`
2. `&lt;` with `<`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are u trying to process the XML and want to replace the special chanracters in XML? In XSLT you cant use < or > .Please eloborate a litte moe

Comment: Please post a sample of some input and desired output.

Comment: I am doing this in the scope of Datastage tool, I get xml messages in the MQ server and we read the XML messages from here and process them and load to the teradata DB. for processing i have to replace the escaped characters in the xml messages e.g &gt; be replaced by '>' and &lt; by '<' sample xml messages is given below.

<ServiceData>&lt;ServiceDocuments&gt;&lt;ServiceContext&gt;&lt;CommBankOriginatingEntity&gt;CBA&lt;/CommBankOriginatingEntity&gt;&lt;CommBankPeopleSoftId&gt;996642242&lt;/CommBankPeopleSoftId&gt
cant post the complete message.

Comment: can you edit your original question, to put the sample input/output in there, since it won't fit in a comment?

Comment: does the recipient of your processing (e.g. the teradata db) expect XML? or text? That will determine what the XSLT should do.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to output character entity as the character represented, you have two scenarios:

1.- Your output method is not `text`: the only way is DOE as in

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;</xsl:text>
```

Output:

>

2.- Your output method is `text`: just output as-is because it does not perform any escape.